# CompiledFunction::cfse: "Compiled expression X should be a machine-size integer

Tags: compile, machine-precision

I am trying to use a compiled function in order to save time...

```
LegrendeTransform = Compile[{y},  MaxValue[Sin[x] - x *y  , x]]
```

Now I want to to evaluate and plot:

```
Plot[{LegrendeTransform[y]}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

But I get this error:

```
CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression 0.9995462353179709` should be a machine-size integer. >>
CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 1; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>
```

Could you explain the reason for this result? The number 0.9995462353179709 is so similar to 1 that I would have no problem if Mathematica decides to approximate it with an integer....

A.

Comment: How about `Compile[{{y, _Real}}, __]`.

Comment: This question can not be answered completely without additional information. One thing is certain: `MaxValue` cannot be compiled down, so the whole exercise is likely to be doomed to fail.

Comment: @RiemannZeta `Compile[{{y, _Real}}, __]` I get the same error

Comment: @halirutan . I saw that the problem occurs with a generic function (and edited the question accordingly). The point is that I can not compile any MaxValue function. Could you explain me why, please? Is there another method to make the function faster?  Thanks.

Comment: @altroware I voted to reopen your question since it is now self-contained. I give you an answer after it is open again.

Comment: @altroware Btw, now that you have earned enough reputation, you can always [visit the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica). I might be around for some time and can give you your answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get this error message because the compiler cannot deduce the type of the `MaxValue` expression. Therefore, it assumes that it is an integer and it gives a message, when a real number is returned. The solution is simple: Tell the compiler that the expression involving `MaxValue` is of type `_Real`

```
LegrendeTransform = Compile[{y},
  MaxValue[Sin[x] - x*y, x], {{MaxValue[_, _], _Real}}];

LegrendeTransform[.5]

(* 0.342427 *)
```

This doesn't solve the underlying problem that `MaxValue` cannot be compiled. Please see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096/187) for a list of compilable functions. In general, algorithms which involve algebraic (opposed to *numeric*) calculations are very unlikely to be compilable.

### Update

> I understood that this function is not "compilable" as it is algebraic, but it seems that with your modification MaxValue is compiled. What does this mean?

It does mean that although you can create a compiled function, your code or not all of your code runs in compiled form. You can use `CompilePrint` to check this. In the following you see, that in the compiled function nothing happens except that your parameter `R0` is assigned. The whole work is done by a `MainEvaluated` call. This means the compiled function leaves its (fast) environment and *asks* the kernel (just as you would do in the notebook) for the answer. It gets the answer back and gives it then to you. Therefore, this is without doubt a way to make your computation slower

```
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
CompilePrint[LegrendeTransform]

(* "
        1 argument
        2 Real registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        R0 = A1
        Result = R1

1   R1 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{y}, MaxValue[Sin[x] - x y, x]][ R0]]
2   Return
" *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I get also this warning: `LegrendeTransform[.7]

During evaluation of In[389]:= NMaximize::cvdiv: Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded. >>

Out[389]= 16062.5 `

Perhaps this is related to a different problem. I understood that this function is not "compilable" as it is algebraic, but it seems that with your modification `MaxValue` is compiled. What does this mean?

Comment: @altroware See my update in the answer. Your other error is related to `MaxValue` itself and you should get it even if you call the uncompiled function in the notebook. This error comes from the form of your target-function you want to maximize.

Comment: Isn't MaxValue[Sin[x] - x *y  , x] unbounded for any finite real y?

Comment: @Ymareth Yes, for all `y!=0`. The `Sin` was a badly chosen toy-example, since the OP's real function was probably too complex to post.

Comment: @Ymareth Ops sorry... this in fact detected by Mathematica (see my first comment).